# angular js ng-repeat in one textarea element

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, angularjs

--> I would like to  fill data in textarea by  one textarea element.

--> For the reason ,when data in mysql is updated  ,I can  type in the textarea by data in textarea is still.

i try ng-repeat pull the each data.

```
 < textarea ng-repeat="task in tasks" task="task" class="task" ></textarea>


 $scope.tasks = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < 301; i++) {
        $scope.tasks.push({
            id: i,
            title: 'Task ' + i, 
            date: date
        });
    }
```

this --> http://jsfiddle.net/3cd6z1vx/
but is not solution .

I can  push data into textarea by data which is typing and data from mysql  still show ?

Comment: Didn't understand your question. You have few text areas which are filled with task which is an object. What do you want to do?

Comment: sorry sir , In example is show  many textarea  by using ng-repeat .but I want push data in  one textarea by using ng-repeat or another way. 
thanks you.

Comment: Ok. So if I understand correctly, you want to have just one textarea and want to push data into that textarea received from mysql. This data may come in chunks and you want to display as it comes. Is that right?

Comment: You don't need ng-repeat. Just update the ngModel variable (tasks) in your controller and it'll automatically show the content in the text area as you update the model.

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/9h2tdL6t/  ?   but   while i 'm typing ,i want to my typing   is not overridden and data from mysql is still update

Answer (score 0):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/u0d1j7hg/2/

Essentially I just added another scope variable to hold the task lines then on refresh built a string for that task. I then set the ng-model to the text area.

I can't see any way to inject directives inside a text area.

Textarea

```
ng-model="prettyTasks"
```

Controller

```
$scope.prettyTasks = [];  
$scope.refresh = function() {
    $scope.prettyTasks = [];  
    console.log("refreshing")
    $scope.tasks = angular.copy($scope.tasks);
    for (var i = 1; i < $scope.tasks.length; i++) {
        var line = $scope.tasks[i].title +" "+moment($scope.tasks[i].date).fromNow()+"\r\n";
        $scope.prettyTasks.push(line);
    }
};
$scope.refresh();
```

Comment: sorry sir  ,I create new one http://jsfiddle.net/9h2tdL6t/   
 `code <!-- I would like  to get this

   <textarea >

{{friends.a[0]}}{{friends.b[0]}}{{friends.c[0]}}
{{friends.a[1]}}{{friends.b[1]}}{{friends.c[1]}}.....

</textarea>   ` 

thanks

Comment: in this: http://jsfiddle.net/u0d1j7hg/2/    when i click  refresh button,the textarea   which i'm typing   is rewritten by data in ng-model.


I want to my typing is still when the data from mysql updated.  thank you

Comment: Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u0d1j7hg/3/ Changed the prettyTasks variable to be a string and just appending new data to it.